# reindexing elastic search does not return all documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, reindex

I have about 1.5 million documents in my elastic search. I'm hoping to reindex them so that each index filters documents containing certain keywords, and one (`null index`) that do not contain any of the keywords I specified in other indices. I'm not sure why my indices returned fewer documents than expected. Particularly I'm expecting about 1.2 million documents in the
`null index` but it only returned about 30k documents in the new index. Would appreciate ideas on what I've done wrong here!

This is how I reindex documents containing certain keywords in multiple fields

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://abcdef2344:9200/_reindex' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "source": {
    "index": "mydocs_email_*",
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "fields": [
                      "content",
                      "meta.raw.Message:Raw-Header:Subject"
                    ],
                    "query": "keyword1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "fields": [
                      "content",
                      "meta.raw.Message:Raw-Header:Subject"
                    ],
                    "query": "keyword2"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "analysis_keywords"
  }
}'
```

Then I use `must_not` to create another index that do not contain `keyword1` and `keyword2`.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://abcdef2344:9200/_reindex' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "source": {
    "index": "mydocs_email_*",
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": [
                {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "fields": [
                      "content",
                      "meta.raw.Message:Raw-Header:Subject"
                    ],
                    "query": "keyword1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "fields": [
                      "content",
                      "meta.raw.Message:Raw-Header:Subject"
                    ],
                    "query": "keyword2"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "analysis_null"
  }
}'
```

The `null index` returned 29.7k documents. From the error message it looks like I should expect 1.28 million files. It also said I need to increase the number of fields in the index - which I also did after running the codes above. Though the number of files still stay the same.

```
{"took":53251,"timed_out":false,"total":1277428,"updated":243,"created":29755,"deleted":0,"batches":30,"version_conflicts":0,"noops":0,"retries":{"bulk":0,"search":0},"throttled_millis":0,"requests_per_second":-1.0,"throttled_until_millis":0,"failures":[{"index":"analysis_null","type":"_doc","id":"/email/.......msg","cause":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Limit of total fields [1000] in index [analysis_null] has been exceeded"},"status":400}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means exactly what it says -- a hard limit in the total number of fields was exceeded during the reindex.

Doesn't changing that setting *before* reindexing solve the problem?

```
DELETE analysis_null

PUT analysis_null
{
  "settings": {
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 10000
  }
}
```

Comment: changing the total fields limit before reindexing isn't an option from what I came across so far. `{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason" : "no such index [analysis_null]`. The new index needs to be created first before adjusting the limit. Unless there are ways to update the field limit at the same time when reindexing occurs?

Comment: have you tried exactly what stands above? a simple `PUT analysis_null` call should be OK